# Content provider with listview and many-to-many relationships

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-contentprovider

I've created a content provider for my app, I'm using it in my main activity with CursorLoader and a listview. The listview displays some Elements. An Element can be bound to many tags.

I defined 3 tables : Element (_id, description), Tag (_id, description), ElementTag (idElement, idTag).

In the query method of the content provider, I do my join but since an Element can have many tags. I get something like in my listview (which is also the result of my query) :

- Element1 | Tag1
- Element1 | Tag2
- Element1 | Tag3

But I would like :

- Element1 Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 (first cell)

I though about not making the join between the Elements and the Tags but in this case I should query the tags for each element in the Cursor Adapter (which is bad I guess).

I've also read on a thread that maybe denormalization is the best idea (make a column in the Element table containing the tags of an element separated by commas). But this will be slow when I would like to get all the elements containing a tag.

Maybe I have to let down the whole CursorLoader thing and just make one big hashmap thanks to the join query ?

I'd really appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, here my workaround :

I don't do any join between the tables ELEMENT and TAG in the content provider. I load only elements so I have only one line per element in the list view.
I implement a method loadContent in the CursorAdapter, I load my tags and tags/elements relationship tables in two hashmaps.

This method is called in the CursorAdapter constructor and when onContentChanged() is called (this method is called thanks to the flag CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER).

Then in the bindView method of the CursorAdapter, when treating the cursor current element, I get all the tags bound to my element thanks to the two hashmaps.

If someone is interested, I can provide some code.